# deleted the google shortcut widget which shows all the google apps

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, default-applications, moto-x

I accidentally deleted the google shortcut widget which shows all the google apps on my x play android lollipop how do i get it back?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't a widget, but just a folder where app shortcuts are put together by default. You can create them by just "drag and drop" an icon over another icon and create a folder. Then you can rename it to "Google" or an app category or whatever you like. Look at the screenshots for a more clear understanding on how to bring back the Folder,

<sub>Screenshots - Click to enlarge image:</sub>

Here's the default folder named Google with Google apps inside it,

[image: scr1]

Pull Google apps from your Menu drawer by long pressing it and pasting on your home screen. Now merge these two app icons to create a folder.

[image: scr2]

After merging the two icons it will be displayed as a folder named "Unnamed folder". You can press and edit it's name to "Google".

[image: scr3]

Finally, after you put all your Google apps into the folder, it would look [like this](http://i-cdn.phonearena.com/images/articles/178948-image/Heres-what-an-app-folder-the-Google-folder-in-our-case-looks-like-once-you-tap-on-it..jpg),

[image: scr4]

Comment: I see. So can you tell what "home screen - -> Shortcut - - > Google Widget" would achieve, as mentioned in [this answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/125435/96277)? I've several of Google apps disabled so I can't test anything here satisfactorily.

Comment: @Firelord There is no "Shortcut"(in my 5.0 L) displayed when long pressing Home screen. The only three options that are shown in my Moto are "Wallpapers", "Widgets" and "Settings". May be he is using a different launcher I guess. But this is what is displayed in Google Now Launcher.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by long pressing on the home screen - -> Shortcut - - > Google Widget. hope that helps.